# Activation Protection Technologies in Windows 8

Tags: windows, drm

Microsoft has implemented a new activation protection with SLIC 3.0, how does this technology work - specifically as compared to the SLIC used in Windows 7?

Answer (score 6):

So I looked this up how it works and found a [nice article](http://www.technize.net/oem-activation-3-0-in-windows-8-will-prevent-slic-activation-hacks/). An excerpt:

*Now Microsoft is planning to release OEM 3.0 in Windows 8 which will enable more security against piracy. So what is OEM 3.0? OEM 3.0 will let Windows 8 to be installed on only one PC and the digital product key will be generated on that PC. The digital product key will only be valid for that PC. If you want to reinstall or reactivate Windows 8 again, you’ll need to have the recovery media provided by your OEM manufacturer. This will make Windows 8 very hard to be cracked because even if Windows 8 is cracked, it will not be able to be used more than once.*